about uniformly convergence for a sequence of functions
for $x\in (0,1] $ let
$f_n(x)= |x- \frac{1}{n}|$ if $x\le \frac{n+1}{2n}$
$f_n(x)=1-x$  if  $ x\ge \frac{n+1}{2n}$
and
$f(x)= -|x-\frac{1}{2}|+\frac{1}{2}$
prove that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f$.
I can see that it converges pointwise but I tried to prove the uniformly convergence  with definition or with using that {$\sup|f_n(x)-f(x)|$} converges to zero. but I couldn't prove it. it looks very complicated.

Can you compute the sup of |f_n-f| for each n?

Perhaps it will be easier for you to observe that $f(x)=x$ for $0\le x\le 1/2$ and $f(x)=1-x$ for $1/2\le x\le 1.$ Morevoer $f_n(x)=x-1/n$ for $1/n\le x\le 1/2.$

@LidingYao I could not

@RyszardSzwarc for $f$ I can see that and I tried to use it but I again I could't prove the uniformly convergence. for $f_n$ how can you see that $x \le \frac{1}{2} $ ?

When $1/n\le x\le 1/2$ we have $f(x)-f_n(x)=1/n,$ for $1/n\le x\le 1/2.$ Next $|f_n(x)-f(x)|=|(1/n-x)-x|\le 3/n$ for $0\le x\le 1/n.$ The coefficient $3$ can be replaced by $1,$ but it is not essential.

@RyszardSzwarc  I have a question. if x≥1/2
how I can write $f_n$(x)
? if x is close to 1 then no problem but if x is too close to 1/2 then how I can write the inequality?

For $x\ge {n+1\over 2n+1}={1\over 2}+{1\over 2(2n+1)}$ we have $f_n(x)=1-x=f(x).$ For ${1\over 2}\le x\le {1\over 2}+{1\over 2(2n+1)}$ we have $f_n(x)=x-{1\over n},$ when $n\ge 2.$ On this interval we get $f_n(x)-f(x)=x-{1\over n}-(1-x)=(2x-1)-{1\over n}.$ Hence $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\le 2(x-{1\over 2})+{1\over n}\le {1\over 2n+1}+{1\over n}.$
